# How to scan the ECU Delphi MT05?

Tags: ecu

The ECU (Engine Control Unit) MT05 from Delphi is used today in many motorbikes and ATV's:

- Regal Raptor (Raptor, Daytona and Spider 350)
- AJP (PR7)
- Benelli (BN600)
- CFmoto (Terralander X8)
- Zongshen (RX3)
- Zhejiang (TR125)
- Hyosung (GT650RC)
- Scomadi scooters
- Riya scooters
- Quadro scooters
- and more...

But this ECU is not OBD2 compliant and so all current OBD2 scanner software will fail to read even the most basic parameters like "Engine speed".

I want to read the current fault code (DTC).
How can I do this?

[image: Delphi MT05 ECU]

Comment: Bud, you are a genius!! With you software can reprogram the ecu or is only for read?

Comment: @Elmue valid point, but there's [a minimum reputation requirement for comments](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) 

Comment: I need your help for MT05 ECM. I need CAN matrix of this ECM for showing these value on display with CAN communication.
It appreciate if you could provide me MT05 ECM CAN messages ID's and other data. Thanks and Regards,
Ravinder

Comment: This is wrong place for this type of questions. Please send me an email. You find my email in the Help at the bottom or on my homepage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After investigating a lot I found that there is only one software able to communicate with this ECU.
It is the ancient **PCHUD** from Delco which is mentioned in the manual of the Delphi MT05.

But this program has been written in 1993 for Windows 3.
It does not run on a 64 bit Windows which is the standard nowadays.
It is quite primitive and does not support ELM 327 adapters (which did not exist in 1993)

So I began to reverse engineer this old software (which was difficult to find) and wrote my own program which now replaces it: **HUD ECU Hacker**

I designed HUD ECU Hacker as "community software".
This means that the program is 100% configurable by the user in an XML file.
This "parameter file" contains the commands sent to the ECU and how to interpret the responses.
This allows to adapt HUD ECU Hacker also to other ECU's.

Meanwhile also the Liteon MC21, Lifan EFI 9 and Yeson 28S ECUs have been added. Also support for **CAN bus** (OBD2 scanning and sniffing) has been added. Supported protocols: ISO9141, ISO14230, ISO15765, CAN Raw.

The program is still growing. I added lots of new features in the last months.

Now it can also download the **flash memory** from the MT05 ECU with the calibration tables, correct the checksum and program the flash memory (tuning).

HUD ECU Hacker finds **calibration tables** automatically in a flash memory file. It finds approx 170 tables and 500 scalar values.
Calibration tables can also be displayed as 3D model.

Download and detailed description here:
https://netcult.ch/elmue/HUD%20ECU%20Hacker/

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Control]

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Dashboard]

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Graph]

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Delphi MT05 Calibration Table Tuning]

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Delphi MT05 Calibration Table Tuning 3D]

Comment: hey @elmune, great software.
I am self-learning and wanted to know from which setting I can adjust the rev limiter. 
I tried adjusting "hi-low limit OSFCO" but I am not getting anywhere. 
My bike has an NC450 engine with an MT05.2 ECU.
Stock Ecu is wantao, similar to mt05 but not tuneable by this software.

Comment: This is not the right place to discuss your problem. And with that sparse information it is impossible to give any useful answer.